# Position element under its parent with :after

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I want to add a background under a button when hovering over it. I would like to make use of the :after pseudo selector in order to avoid including more markup.

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.25s ease all;
}

button:after {
  opacity: 0;
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  transition: 0.25s ease opacity;
}

button:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello world</button>
```

As you can see when hovering the red background is placed on top of the button's background which is not what I want.

Any ideas on how could I achieve this effect?

Here is a demo: https://codepen.io/cesalberca/pen/EEVMVx

Comment: why not simply change the background of button ?

Comment: You could just add `button:hover {box-shadow: 3px 3px 1px red;}` and remove the whole `button:after`.

Comment: The background is going to be a blurred gradient, so using box-shadow is not the go to solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the z-index from the button:

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  transition: 0.25s ease all;
}

button:after {
  opacity: 0;
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  transition: 0.25s ease opacity;
}

button:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button>Hello world</button>
```

Edit per comments (you need a span in the button):

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
}

button span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.25s ease all;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

button:after {
  opacity: 0;
  content: "";
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  transition: 0.25s ease opacity;
}

button:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button><span>Hello world</span></button>
```

Comment: Your solution works here but for the love of me I can't seem to get it working in my page :( I think some styling must be overriden some how and I don't know what.

Comment: Inspect the button - see if it has a z-index applied elsewhere

Comment: I don't think your solution is going to work for me... I've found out the I must set the parent of the button to have position absolute and set a z-index of 1. However in a fixed positioned element it doesn't work.

Comment: You will need to wrap the text in a span then and put the styling on that - see edit above

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

No extra element  needed.

```css
button {
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  transition: all .25s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 5%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

button:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<button>Submit</button>
```